# Error to retrieve image from firebase for recycler view in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment

I want to retrieve image for recycler view in fragment

code of MovieActivity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoadingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        setupViewFragment();
    }
    setupToolbar();
    setupBottomNavigation();
}

private void setupViewFragment() {
    // show discover movies fragment by default
    DiscoverMoviesFragment discoverMoviesFragment = DiscoverMoviesFragment.newInstance();
    ActivityUtils.replaceFragmentInActivity(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), discoverMoviesFragment, R.id.fragment_container);
}

private void setupBottomNavigation() {
    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_home:
                    ActivityUtils.replaceFragmentInActivity(
                            getSupportFragmentManager(), HomeFragment.newInstance(),
                            R.id.fragment_container);
                    //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                            //,HomeActivity.class));
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_discover:
                    ActivityUtils.replaceFragmentInActivity(
                            getSupportFragmentManager(), DiscoverMoviesFragment.newInstance(),
                            R.id.fragment_container);
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_favorites:
                    ActivityUtils.replaceFragmentInActivity(
                            getSupportFragmentManager(), FavoritesFragment.newInstance(),
                            R.id.fragment_container);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void setupToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

}
`

code for HomeFragment :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoadingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        setupViewFragment();
    }
    setupToolbar();
    setupBottomNavigation();
}

private void setupViewFragment() {
    // show discover movies fragment by default
    DiscoverMoviesFragment discoverMoviesFragment = DiscoverMoviesFragment.newInstance();
    ActivityUtils.replaceFragmentInActivity(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), discoverMoviesFragment, R.id.fragment_container);
}

private void setupBottomNavigation() {
    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_home:
                    ActivityUtils.replaceFragmentInActivity(
                            getSupportFragmentManager(), HomeFragment.newInstance(),
                            R.id.fragment_container);
                    //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                            //,HomeActivity.class));
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_discover:
                    ActivityUtils.replaceFragmentInActivity(
                            getSupportFragmentManager(), DiscoverMoviesFragment.newInstance(),
                            R.id.fragment_container);
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_favorites:
                    ActivityUtils.replaceFragmentInActivity(
                            getSupportFragmentManager(), FavoritesFragment.newInstance(),
                            R.id.fragment_container);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void setupToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

}

code for HomeAdapter :

```
public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Upload> mUploads;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public HomeAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
    mContext = context;
    mUploads = uploads;
}

@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
    Picasso.get()
            .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .centerInside()
            .fit()
            .into(holder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUploads.size();
}

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
        View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    public TextView textViewName;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                mListener.onItemClick(position);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Action");
        MenuItem doWhatever = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Do whatever");
        MenuItem delete = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Delete");
        doWhatever.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case 1:
                        mListener.onWhatEverClick(position);
                        return true;
                    case 2:
                        mListener.onDeleteClick(position);
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);

    void onWhatEverClick(int position);

    void onDeleteClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
```

}

this is the error :

`C:\Users\User\Desktop\PopularMovies\app\src\main\java\com\ajdi\yassin\popularmovies\ui\movieslist\home\HomeFragment.java:65: error: incompatible types: HomeFragment cannot be converted to Context

```
    mAdapter = new HomeAdapter(HomeFragment.this, mUploads);`
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use **getApplicationContext()** ,because **HomeFragment.this** is consider as an Activity and in your HomeAdapter constructor you have passed **Context**.

**Replace:**

```
 mAdapter = new HomeAdapter(HomeFragment.this, mUploads);
```

**To:**

```
 mAdapter = new HomeAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mUploads);
```